# Payment Options From Shopping Cart

Tags: asp.net, paypal, webforms, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am using `ASP.NET` with my code behind in `C#` and I am working on setting up a shopping cart to allow payment online using `Paypal`  This is great!  Well now I need an option from my shopping cart to allow the option of "Pay In Store."  Following the tutorial [Webforms And Paypal](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal)and things are great, except I do not see anyway to allow check-out w/o `Paypal` info being entered for payment.

Is their a way in `ASP.Net` and `C#` to give the user the option to EITHER pay with paypal OR pay in store?

**EDIT:**
Is their an e-commerce asp.net program that will allow me to use integrate both the paypal fast checkout as well as a pay-in-store option?

Comment: The way you presented the question made me smile

Comment: Yes of course there _"is a way in ASP.net"_ and that involves things like understanding _merchant accounts, compliance, security, and/or any other payment options / flows for ecommerce operations you want_ - which makes your question **too broad**. You can look into [Pro services](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/) offered by Paypal to start. Hth.

Comment: @EdSF - it looks like Pro services will work for accepting credit/debit cards (I was going to use Express Check-Out).  What would be a method of adding say a checkbox or radio button to click if you want to pay in-store?

Comment: Unsure what you are asking - you can refer to any popular shopping site that provides PayPal and "in store" to see how they provide the UI/options choices to the user. Pick one you think is appropriate for your users. Technology stack (ASP.Net or whatever) is irrelevant. You can handle any flow in the "event model" of Web Forms, or POST/GET in MVC (or even Web Forms too, if you wanted).